# Not another Sencha Touch 2 vs JQMobile 1.2.0 Performance Comparison Thread

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch-2

I know this has been asked a million times but i can't seem to find a good comparison that is with the new Sencha Touch 2 and the currently released and optimized JQMobile 1.2.0 or 1.1.1 even.

My main concern is i have worked with both but only with the old non optimized version of JQMobile so my question is.

How big is the improvement of the new JQuery Mobile that was just released in comparison to Sencha Touch 2 when it comes to packaging it into a native mobile application?

THanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't made a Sencha App yet (although the demos look snappy), but I have just completed a jQuery Mobile app that I upgraded to 1.1.1 shortly before completing. The performance improvement was minimal. In short, jQuery Mobile performance just isn't very good at all if you're making a complex app. For simple stuff, it's great, but if you are building anything of greater size and complexity you really ought to look elsewhere. If you do go JQM be sure to search around for tips on how to keep performance up, but do know that even if you follow them all you may end up disappointed. On a sidenote JQM still has all sorts of obnoxious bugs when it comes to things like fixed headers and other visual elements...it's really just not worth using (yet) in anything but the simplest of use cases.

Comment: k thanks, you are right i have tried comparing the two and for major applications you can really notice the difference between sencha and jqmobile.